# How do you update all embedded documents for a specific column in a table in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Currently I have an `address` column that is an embedded document in my `users` table.  The `address` column contains the `_id` for related rows in the `address` table. Each `user` can have many `addresses` so there can be multiple embedded documents in the `user` `address` column if that user had more than one address.

How do I delete all `address` embedded documents for a specific address `id`?  In my case, when a user deletes an address, I want to delete that specific address from **ALL** of the `address` embedded documents in the users table.

Is this possible in the rails console?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
User.where('addresses.id' => address.id).each do |u|
  u.addresses.where(:id => address.id).delete
  u.save
end
```

Comment: This does not work.  It doesn't find it so is returning nil. I even tried `User.where('addresses.id' => address.id).first` and it is returning nil.

Comment: How get you address from your user ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
while User.where('addresses._id' => address.id).count > 0
  User.collection.update({'addresses._id' => address.id},
      {'$pull' => { :addresses => { '_id' => address.id } } },
      :multi => true)
end
```

This will not run any callbacks. If you need any callbacks, you should use shingara's method but replace `delete` with `destroy`

Comment: This is not doing anything. I even tried `User.where('addresses._id' => address.id)` and it returns nil.  Its like its not seeing the embedded documents.

Comment: @Goalie In case you are not setting custom id for addresses and letting mongo set the ID, then none of the documents will have the same ID(even embedded ones). There must be some other way for you to identify if two addresses are same or not. You should use that instead of `'addresses._id' => address.id`